# Programmatically Add ContentTemplate to TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, contenttemplate

I have this TabControl

```
        <TabControl x:Name="tcProvince" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkingEntity.Rates.CodeByProvinceCollection, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="tcProvince_SelectionChanged" >
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <max:MaxGrid>
                    <max:MaxGrid.RowDefinitions>

                    </max:MaxGrid.RowDefinitions>
                    <max:MaxGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    </max:MaxGrid.ColumnDefinitions>


                </max:MaxGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

    </TabControl>
```

This generate a tab like this: 
[image]

Then inside of each Tab I want to create a dynamic grid like this:

```
+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| 2016  |  2017 | 2018   |  2019 |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| xxx   |   xxxx| xxxx   | xxxxx |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+
```

The `year` and `xxx` are value entered by the customer. To add a year he has to click on a button, and the `xxx` are TextBox input where he can edit it anytime.
So the I have no idea how many year and value I will get.

My pseudo code look a bit like:

- On TabControlSelectionChange
- If the Grid has been generated, just display it.
- otherwise:
- Grab the DataTemplate (or create a new one, doesn't really matter)
- Generate the columns according to the collection
- insert values in cells
- create binding for the `TextBox`
- push the new grid to the TabItem

I have Almost every tools to do this. I just can figured out, how to set the new grid as a content of the TabItem, since the TabItem is the Type of my collection's content

Comment: Looks like quick work for [HeaderedItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a `ContentTemplate`

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, i'll take a look this, seems a better option than the grid. I edited the post, to include the real question.

Comment: Do it this way and you can use the same datatemplate for all of them and just feed the items via ItemSource binding from the vm. I mean it's basically a recycle-able itemscontrol.